# Listview populated with empty entities

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have an `ObservableCollection` of `IDevice` which contains a collection bluetooth devices in the periphery.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public ObservableCollection<IDevice> Devices { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        Devices = new ObservableCollection<IDevice>();
        Padding = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);
        var listView = new ListView();
        listView.ItemsSource = Devices;
        Content = listView;
        Refreshcmd();
    }

    public void Refreshcmd()
    {
        var adapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;
        adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) => Devices.Add(a.Device);
        adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
    }
}
```

My problem is, that the listview is populated with empty entities as well, besides the actual Bluetooth devices, which results in a very long list with actual devices on every 5th line or so.

I suspect that the error occurs upon adding data to `Devices`. I believe A fix would be to alter the lambda expression with a condition, so that device != empty ish. Also, it could maybe be possible to go the other way around, and somehow tell the listview that it shouldn't show "empty" data.

I'm just unsure how i would go about doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) => 
{
  // test here for any conditions you want to exclude
  if (a.Device != null) {
    Devices.Add(a.Device);
  }
}
```

Comment: Very cool. Thank you! I might need to study more on these lambda expressions!